# Click event not firing on GWT site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gwt, automation

I am attempting to automate testing on the client side of a GWT built site.
I have been able to run through all the DOM elements and find the span element which is clickable I tried the click() method but it never fires.

This can only be done on the client-side. I cannot adjust the source code to contain any ID's or names.

Here is my HTML code from the scratch pad. This does find the div that contains the table and get the span tag which is inside the first td.

```
    <div tabindex="1779" id="isc_8C" style="left: 0px; top: 62px; width: 1566px; height: 165px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; position: absolute; z-index: 201998; cursor: default; background-color: white;" onfocus="isc.EH.focusInCanvas(ResultsGrid_1_body,true);"
onblur="if(window.isc)isc.EH.blurFocusCanvas(ResultsGrid_1_body,true);" onscroll="return ResultsGrid_1_body.$lh()" eventproxy="ResultsGrid_1_body">
    <div id="isc_8B" style="width: 1566px; position: relative; z-index: 1000;">
        <form onsubmit="return false;" action="javascript:void(0)">
            <div id="ResultsGrid_1_body$28s" style="width: 1px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; display: none;"><span style='width: 1px; height: 0px; vertical-align: text-top; display: inline-block;'></span>
            </div>
            <table width="1550" class="listTable" id="isc_8Ctable" role="presentation" style="overflow: hidden; table-layout: fixed;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                <tbody>
                    <tr role="listitem" aria-selected="true" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="1">
                        <td width="396" align="left" class="tallCellSelectedOver" style="height: 16px; overflow: hidden;">
                            <span class="clickable">748754434564</span>
                        </td>
                        <td width="180" align="left" class="tallCellSelectedOver" style="height: 16px; overflow: hidden;">Jon, smith</td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div id="ResultsGrid_1_body$284" style="width: 1px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; display: none;"><span style='width: 1px; height: 0px; vertical-align: text-top; display: inline-block;'></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the script code is

```
$('div [eventproxy=ResultsGrid_1_body] table td span').click();
```

How can I perform a click on the span tag?

Comment: The span is already clickable.But in the source code of span the click attribute is not defined, Not sure how GWT works here without click event. what ever clickable is happening today the same I need to do from automation.

Answer (score 0):

try to associate id with the span , then add the function just before the end of body tag or if including a js file, then call it just above the body tag, not at the starting.

```
<span id="sp"> </span>
```

working example can be seen here

https://jsfiddle.net/2b645Lup/5/

Comment: @Rnayak.I can define the id here through Automation.The span is already clickable.But in the source code of span the click attribute is not defined, Not sure how GWT works here without click event. what ever clickable is happening today the same I need to do from automation.